# Gravity Forms Ajax Not Working

Tags: ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Using Gravity Forms 1.8.1 , no other plugins activated.
Tested also with latest build 1.9.2
Tested using Divi theme, as well as 2015 theme with same results.
Tested in Chrome and Firefox with same results.

Added the following shortcode:

```
[gravityform id="1" name="test-form-1" ajax="true"]
```

The form submits, but always with non-ajax and refreshes the page. I can tell this by looking at the tab and viewing the 'Net' tabs in Chrome's developer tools and Firebug in Firefox. The XHR requests are empty, and the requests clear and post normally as they would if it was a non-ajax request.

This should work. I get no errors or conflicts when looking at Firebug's console tab. I found no one experiencing similar problems although not really sure how many gravity form users are paying attention to the behavior in firebug.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Let me know what it is!

---

**Relevant form code generated by Gravity Forms**

```
<div id="gform_wrapper_1" class="gf_browser_gecko gform_wrapper">
   <a class="gform_anchor" name="gf_1" id="gf_1"></a>
   <form action="/sandbox/#gf_1" id="gform_1" target="gform_ajax_frame_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <div class="gform_heading">
         <h3 class="gform_title">test-form-1</h3>
         <span class="gform_description"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="gform_body">
         <ul class="gform_fields top_label description_below" id="gform_fields_1">
            <li class="gfield               gfield_contains_required" id="field_1_1">
               <label for="input_1_1" class="gfield_label">Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
               <div class="ginput_container"><input type="text" tabindex="1" class="medium" value="Joe Smith" id="input_1_1" name="input_1"></div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;}  if( !jQuery(&quot;#gform_1&quot;)[0].checkValidity || jQuery(&quot;#gform_1&quot;)[0].checkValidity()){window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;} " tabindex="2" value="Submit" class="button gform_button" id="gform_submit_button_1"><input type="hidden" value="form_id=1&amp;title=1&amp;description=1&amp;tabindex=1" name="gform_ajax">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="is_submit_1" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="gform_submit" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="gform_unique_id" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="WyJhOjA6e30iLCJkZjhiZTNiZTg3NDNmMWNlNDNmNTk1N2M0NTY2ZTRiMSJd" name="state_1" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="0" id="gform_target_page_number_1" name="gform_target_page_number_1" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" id="gform_source_page_number_1" name="gform_source_page_number_1" class="gform_hidden">
         <input type="hidden" value="" name="gform_field_values">
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did the accepted solutions work for you? I have Jquery enqueued in head but the form just reloads normally NO data is sent via ajax. The only thing that changes when adding the ajax=true is that the spinner shows that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure jQuery is enqueued in the head - not the footer.

I'm using the Roots/Sage framework in which it is enqueued in the footer by default - which was causing your exact issue.

Comment: Having seen the answer below, I'd go for that in future.

Answer (score 9):

You should still keep your scripts in the footer for performance reasons. But you need to include this in the `header.php` right above your `<?php wp_head(); ?>`:

```
<?php gravity_form_enqueue_scripts(1,true) ?>
```

with 1 being the id of the form.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Nate Beers answer, If you have a reCAPTCHA on your form AJAX will not work. reCAPTCHA is not compatible with AJAX.

See issue on gravity forms forum.
https://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/topic/ajax-submission-not-working-on-hard-coded-form#post-36914

I went ahead and used the Gravity Forms anti-spam honeypot as a reCAPTCHA alternative on the form settings page.

Comment: This may have been true at some point but as of 2019 reCaptcha works fine with Gravity Forms AJAX.